# Discord PY On member Join add Roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am a bit new to Discord PY and am looking for a way to add roles if a person DM's a Key to the bot.
I researched and typed this code but am getting errors please Help
The Code IS

```
Mod = 789737793042776074


@Client.event
async def on_member_join(person):
    async for guild in Client.fetch_guilds(limit=150):
        channel = person
        await channel.send(f"Thanks for Joining {guild.name}")
        reply = await Client.wait_for('message', timeout=60)
        if reply.content == 'STron':
#         role = get(guild.roles, id = Mod)
          await channel.send('Sshh I Gave you Moderator')
          await person.add_roles(id = Mod)
```

I am getting an error

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 28, in on_member_join
    await person.add_roles(id = Mod)
TypeError: add_roles() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

Comment: Please specify the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get role and then add

```py
Mod = 789737793042776074

@Client.event
async def on_member_join(person):
    await person.send(f"Thanks for Joining {person.guild.name}")
    msg = await Client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: not m.guild and m.author.id == person.id)
    if msg.content == "STron":
        await person.send("Sshh I gave you Moderator")
        await person.add_roles(person.guild.get_role(Mod))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
async def on_member_join(member): 
  role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Role name here")
  await member.add_roles(role)
```

This should help. Try and read the docs or research discord.utils.get

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how does your answer work? It seems simple but what's exactly happening?

Comment: @aaossa all it does it calls the on member join event so that when a member joins the giving guild then that block of code will be executed. In this case role = discord.utils.get .... creates a variable called role with the role data type so then you can add the role because it has the same data type

Comment: That's a good explanation, I think it's valuable enough to be considered part of your answer. I suggest that you update your answer with that description

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(user):
    await user.send(f"Message and variables")
    await user.add_roles(id) ##or await user.add_roles(ctx.guild.get_role(Name or Id))
```